# How to create and use a custom transport channel for gRPC?

Tags: grpc, grpc-c#

I have a lot of experience creating custom transport channels for WCF. Now, we're evaluating gRPC. The first question I cannot find an answer yet. Is it possible to create a custom transport channel for gRPC? Is there a documentation or better an example how to do that? I need to create a very specific custom channel for inter-process communication.

Comment: In short, the answer is no. in Grpc.Core the native layer actually supports adding custom transports but doing so is a lot of work and requires expert knowledge of gRPC C core internals (and you'd need to recompile the native component from scratch) - so I wouldn't recommend going down this path. In grpc-dotnet this is currently also not possible (you need to use the default http2 transport).

Comment: Would support for UDS be any helpful?

Comment: And that stands for Unix Domain Socket? No. The whole question arose because of the potential plans to migrate .NET Framework project to .NET 5.0 which is part of the UWP package bundle and the transport protocol I'm talking about is very specific. It is UWP - service communication and WCF was used as the abstraction layer along with the custom channel implementation. Now the question is what to do if WCF is gone. Apparently in our case the answer is to wait until it is back or there is something else that will work for our case.